# Hidden overflow not working with flexbox and margin auto

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex container with individual child containers within it. Within those child containers, I have a simple content div and a title div. What I am trying to do is centre the title text vertically, but keep it at the top of the box. Then, I am trying to centre the content div in the box, both horizontally and vertically.

I have sort of figured it out (but knowing me this code is a load of drivel), but now when the viewport size decreases, the content text (with overflow: hidden) does not hide when the size decreases. I have figured out that this is down to the margin being set to 0, but I need it to be set to 0 in order for the bloody content div to center!

Any and all help offered is much appreciated. Here is a link to the jsfiddle that I created in order to help you visualise the problem. Change the size of the viewport and you'll see my issue, namely on the "Total cash amongst players" box.

http://jsfiddle.net/mpqbassm/

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.flex-info {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-info.green {
  background: #79B0B4;
}

.flex-info.blue {
  background: #7993B4;
}

.flex-info.foam {
  background: #79B47D;
}

.flex-info.pink {
  background: #9B79B4;
}

.flex-info.red {
  background: #B4797F;
}

.flex-info .flex-title {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flex-info .flex-content {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-info green">
    <div class="flex-title">Number of characters created</div>
    <div class="flex-content">46,401</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-info blue">
    <div class="flex-title">Number of vehicles purchased</div>
    <div class="flex-content">499,012</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-info foam">
    <div class="flex-title">Total cash amongst players</div>
    <div class="flex-content">$192,012,299</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-info red">
    <div class="flex-title">Total bans issued</div>
    <div class="flex-content">12</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stop the content from overflowing, `overflow: hidden` must be on the *parent* container of the element.

In this case, that would be any div with the class `.flex-info`.

Take a look at this in practice below.

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.flex-info {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.flex-info.green {
  background: #79B0B4;
}

.flex-info.blue {
  background: #7993B4;
}

.flex-info.foam {
  background: #79B47D;
}

.flex-info.pink {
  background: #9B79B4;
}

.flex-info.red {
  background: #B4797F;
}

.flex-info .flex-title {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flex-info .flex-content {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-info green">
    <div class="flex-title">Number of characters created</div>
    <div class="flex-content">46,401</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-info blue">
    <div class="flex-title">Number of vehicles purchased</div>
    <div class="flex-content">499,012</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-info foam">
    <div class="flex-title">Total cash amongst players</div>
    <div class="flex-content">$192,012,299</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-info red">
    <div class="flex-title">Total bans issued</div>
    <div class="flex-content">12</div>
  </div>
</div>
```